# Select the first value from autocomplete JavaScript & PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, autocomplete

in the below screenshot I am displaying list of cities list and when I try to enter "Brisbane" its displaying the list of cities and suburbs with name "Brisbane".

[image]

Now I have the following JavaScript for autocomplete function.

```
function selectAutocomplete(e, t) {
    switch (e.target.value = t.item.label, $("input#destinationId").val(""), $("input#hotel_id").val(""), $("input#region_id").val(""), t.item.type) {
    case "1C":
        break;
    case "2S":
        $("input#region_id").val(t.item.value);
        break;
    case "3D":
        $("input#destinationId").val(t.item.value);
        break;
    case "4H":
        $("input#hotel_id").val(t.item.value)
    }
    StopEvent(e)
}

 $("input#keywords").bind("keydown", function (e) {
            13 != e.keyCode && ($("#hotel_id").val(""), $("#destinationId").val(""), $("#region_id").val(""))
```

Full JS code at http://pastebin.com/ThVpLSvC
Site link https://dev.ther8server.com (Please excuse the self signed SSL)

Can anyone help me filling the textbox automatically, that is when someone ends up typing as Brisbane and click on search it should automatically `click` (Cause onclick other hidden fields too are filled) on autocomplete first item and that should fill the textbox named `Keywords`

HTML code

```
<input type="hidden" id="destinationId" name="destinationId" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" id="hotel_id" name="hotel_id" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" id="region_id" name="region_id" value=""/>
<input type="text" id="keywords" value="Enter destination or hotel name" placeholder="Enter destination or hotel name" name="keywords" class="ui-autocomplete-input" onfocus="this.value='';" autocomplete="off"/>
```

Comment: Since you use jquery, why not use jquery-ui, it has auto-complete: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: @Zac - True but this application is extremely big and was developed by someone else. At this stage its really hard to change it to jQuery-UI so just looking for some quick fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After read you code, here is the suggestion rather than an answer:

1. Put the first value inside the box would trigger a logical issue, since it change the input box value, therefore, the auto-complete list would also been changed.
2. To resolve the issue, jquery-ui auto-completion use : auto focus.

To put auto focus in place, please insert into you js after line 422:

```
autoFocus: true,
```

Reading : http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-autoFocus

Comment: You mean in between these two lines? `source: "/ajax/autocomplete"` and `select: selectAutocomplete,` right?

Comment: Thanks Zac, not autoFocus I am looking for something that could do autoselect.

Comment: Tell me what would happen, when you type "P", it auto-select "Pakistan", the Paris in your list is gone. Then you start to delete, when the character become "Pa", the auto-select select "Pakistan" again for you ... or this time it auto-select "Japan" for you.

Comment: No, on `focusout` it should choose the top one.

Comment: If you focus back, the current code would wipe out the content: `onfocus="this.value='';"`. Anyway, if you really want it (which I do not think make user's life easier), you can put the `onblur="get_top_autocomplete_value()"`, then you just need make `selectAutocomplete(e, t)` the `t` become access-able by you new function `get_top_autocomplete_value`

Comment: Thanks, but little confusing can you please give me little more information? May be some example code that suits my scenario?

Comment: On second thought, no, it is the wrong principle and it would not work.

Comment: The problem is - how you know the address left in the box is selected by user or left alone. Left input box has lots situation, give up typing just one of the reason. What about try to select some text in other area, the code auto change the content. You may put lots time to supply a feature, which not suppose to be there anyway. It feels like I try to get some points, rather than follow the best practice. Sorry, I would not help you on it.